# Cannot import "deprecated" class from warnings module

Tags: python

I am using code similar to

```
from warnings import deprecated

@deprecated
def test():
    print("test")

test()
```

I am getting an error (python 3.11) with "cannot load deprecated from warnings" and I was wondering if anybody knows why that is.

I noticed that [warnings.py does infact have that class](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5d72b753889977fa6d2d015499de03f94e16b035/Lib/warnings.py#L518)

Comment: [`warnings.deprecated` will be introduced in Python 3.13](https://docs.python.org/3.13/library/warnings.html#warnings.deprecated), which isn't released yet. You need to use [`typing_extensions.deprecated`](https://typing-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#typing_extensions.deprecated) if you want to use it before Python 3.13.

Comment: @dROOOze Please don't post answers in the comments; post an answer instead :)

Comment: @wjandrea it is in common practice to post answers in the comments when the answers boil down to "I read the documentation for you".

Comment: @larsks Ah yeah, fair enough. I would post a community wiki myself if I thought it would be helpful in the future ([e.g.](/a/64216632/4518341)), but if we're thinking no in this case, probably better to VTC instead.